# Embed video to my website to be visible from android

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I need support to understand how I can embed my youtube video into my website. I need that when I'm visiting my website through android browser, the video should be visible in page and not with the dedicated app.
I tried with the iframe but the video don't start to play.

regards

Comment: Not sure whether there is autoplay these days on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed video from youtube then their it is very esay.
1. Go to video
2. Click on share
3. Click on Embed
Copy the code and paste it in website.